# YAML giving errror for file that is file in YAML Lint

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a Spigot plugin for a friend, and I'm using YAML for a configuration file since the framework supports it directly.  However, when testing it, I'm getting this error:

```
org.bukkit.configuration.InvalidConfigurationException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 2, column 18:
    center-position-x: 0
                     ^
```

Here is my YAML file:

```yaml
# X coord of sphere center
center-position-x: 0
# Y coord of sphere center
center-position-y: 150
# Z coord of sphere center
center-position-z: 0

# Maximum sphere radius in blocks
radius: 10

# World in which this command works
check-world: world

# The world that the command sends you to
send-world: battlegrounds

# Wether you want a semi-sphere facing up (true) or a full sphere (false), use true if your point is on the ground
semi-sphere: true
```

I checked it with [YamlLint](http://www.yamllint.com/) and it says that everything is correct, I checked other Stack Overflow posts, but those were just resolved with fixing bad YAML syntax, I'm honestly not sure what else to do.

EDIT: I was able to reproduce the problem with

```yaml
center-position-x: 0
```

and got the same error.

Comment: Can you try creating a config.yml with only that first `center-position-x: 0` to confirm that it is the problem. Parsers don't always give the exact correct emplacement when showing errors. (Add this to the *What you have tried* in your question) :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, my requests to build wasn't registering so it was using and older, broken version of the YAML file, after changing some project settings, it's now working.